# How do you sandbox a Windows application to a specific Wine prefix like in Snaps?

Tags: wine, snap

I have programs that require different Wine prefixes to work. To start them, I need to open up the terminal and specify which Wine prefix to use before launching. I would like to be able to have it where I can simply click on the application and have Wine automatically open up with that prefix. This is what happens when you install a Windows program off of Synaptic, so I would like to know how they do it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a flatpak program called [bottles](https://usebottles.com/).

It allows you to configure multiple instances of WINE with different versions and much more.

Comment: I have Bottles but I've never had success with it. Does it let you just click on an icon and open an app, or do you have to open Bottles first?

Comment: Left-click probably uses Wine without any settings, but when I right-click, there is an option "Open with Bottles". After that, it opens up a window to choose the preconfigured instance that I'd like to use.

Comment: that may be slightly better than using the terminal but its not what i asked for. there is clearly a way to do it with left click, take for example the foobar2000 snap. you just download it from ubuntu software and it runs without any extra hassle

Answer (score 2):

According to your comments on my previous answer, another option that I can recommend is creating your own `.desktop` files.

Every application on your applications menu has a `.desktop` file. This file determines the logo, title, execution parameters and right-click options. (and probably some other stuff that I'm unaware of)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/path/to/executable
Name=Name of Application
Icon=/path/to/icon
```

AFAIK, these are the bare minimums for a `.desktop` file.

- Type determines the application group it would be in. For example; Games, Settings, Internet, Other...
- Terminal, whether it has a terminal for debugging or not
- Exec, whatever you can run in a single command. It can point to a shell/bash/zsh script to run more complex stuff
- Name and Icon are obvious, there might be a limit for the Icon size, like max 512x512 pixels, but I'm not sure about that.

After creating this file, copy/move it to `~./local/share/applications` for single user setup, or `/usr/share/applications` for multi-user setups.

Comment: This is a good start, but it still doesn't properly integrate the program into the DE. I've actually done this before for a non-WINE program, and I still haven't figured out how to make the program have it's icon/name in the Launcher bar when it's running. Just says "Unknown." You also need to do some manual tinkering to get it to show up in the Right click>Open with menu, which I've also done but forgot how.

Comment: If both of my answers can not satisfy your need, then either I'm not able to fully understand your needs, or you need to clarify your question to be a little more specific. Integrating a program into the DE is over my knowledge, but all I can recommend you is to create your own Snap package, maybe this can satisfy your needs. This Digital Ocean [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-package-and-publish-a-snap-application-on-ubuntu-18-04) is a bit old but it might help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use environment variable [`WINEPREFIX`](https://www.winehq.org/docs/wineserver) and [bubblewrap](https://github.com/containers/bubblewrap) for hand-made sandboxing.

Another option is [sandwine](https://github.com/hartwork/sandwine) and its argument `--dotwine PATH:{ro,rw}`. Please be sure to check its threat model in the readme.